# Im running this code on sql oracle ,but i got error" sql command not properly ended".MY 1st table is emply and second table is department,

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

```
UPDATE emply 
SET e_age = e_age + 10 
FROM emply 
JOIN department ON emply.e_dept = department.d_dpt;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using SQL Server update join syntax, which won't work on Oracle.  One working solution might use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE emply e
SET e_age = e_age + 10
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM department d WHERE d.d_dpt = e.e_dept);
```